# Show/Hide Divs when clicking on donut chart Section

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I have a donut raphael donut chart that I would like when clicked to show a cooresponding div of text.

I tried to set id's for each section and then trigger them with jquery using this code but it is not working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery(".div1, .div2, .div3, .div4").hide();

jQuery("#arched1, #arched2, #arched3, #arched4").bind("click", function () {

   jQuery(".div1, .div2, .div3, .div4").hide();

    if (jQuery(this).attr("id") == "oxbowarc1") {
        jQuery(".div1").show();
    } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "oxbowarc2") {
        jQuery(".div2").show();
    } else if (jQuery(this).attr("id") == "oxbowarc3") {
        jQuery(".div3").show();
    } else {
        jQuery(".div4").show();
    }
});
});
```

What can I do to make this work?

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dll416/17j9Lhwg/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate. The elements are added, or assigned `id`s dynamically, in your code, the jQuery would not recognize them when creating the handler.

Try something like

```
jQuery(container).on("click", "#arched1, #arched2, #arched3, #arched4", function () {
...
```

In essence, your attaching the handler to the container (can be `document`, `"body"` or a more specific element), only for the `id`s mentioned in selector. That way the handler is attached to an element which does exist on documentReady.

I didn't add it to you fiddle since it seems the assignment of `id`s is missing there.

Comment: Ok. So your jquery line would replace the 3rd line in my code above?

Comment: Yes, but replace <container> with either the `document` object, or a selector for an element encapsulating these `div`s

Comment: The assignment of ids are missing? What does that mean? Did I need something more than the p.node.id = 'arched';

Comment: It Worked! Thank you! I used document instead of container.

Comment: Yea, I can only see the sector ids with the inspector when I have it in my development site. Can't figure out how to see them in jsfiddle.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. :) Welcome to SO.